# Wrap blocking code into a Mono flatMap, is this still a non-blocking operation?

Tags: spring, reactive-programming, blocking, nonblocking, reactor

if i wrap blocking code into a flatMap, is this still a non-blocking operation ?

Example:

```
    public Mono<String> foo() {

    Mono.empty().flatMap(obj -> {

        try {

        Object temp = f.get();//are the thread at this point blocked or not ?

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw e;
        }

        return Mono.just("test");

    });
```

So, i think when i wrap blocking code into reactive code, the operation is still non-blocking ? If i am wrong, pls explain it to me.

Answer (score 6):

> if i wrap blocking code into a flatMap, is this still a non-blocking operation ?

flatMap doesn't create new threads for you. For example:

```
Mono.just("abc").flatMap(val -> Mono.just("cba")).subscribe();
```

All the code above will be executed by the current thread that called `subscribe`. So if the mapper function contained a long blocking operation the thread that called subscribe will be blocked as well.

To transform this to an asynchronous operation you can use `subscribeOn(Schedulers.elastic());`

```
 Mono.just("abc").flatMap(val -> Mono.just("cba")).subscribeOn(Schedulers.elastic());
```

Mono and Flux don't create threads, but some operators take `Scheduler` as an extra argument to use such as the `interval` operator, or alter threading model all together such as `subscribeOn`.

One extra thing, in your example the mapper function is never going to be called, since your applying flatMap to an empty mono which completes directly with no values emitted.